# FFMPEG YouTube Live Too Fast

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg, streaming

So I am streaming video and audio to YouTube as follows

### THE CONTEXT

1. First I convert a graphic GIF to an MP4 file

```
ffmpeg -f gif -i graphic.gif -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:-1 temp.mp4
```

2. Then I overlay a PNG with text over the MP4

```
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '.$graphicsPath.'/graphic.mp4
```

3. Then I start the stream the video and combine it with audio using following code (sources.txt is just a concat list *)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i sources.txt -i music.mp3 \
    -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -deinterlace \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset '.$encoding.' -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 \
    -maxrate 800k -bufsize 1400k \
    -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY
```

4. After the stream ends, the code starts over again with a new song to mimic a 247 stream.

### THE ISSUE

So the issue I am having is that it appears to be streaming too fast. It's like the opposite of buffering issues where the buffer is way too long (as in a full song buffered by the time the first one has finished if you open the stream)

Does anyone know how I could throttle the output? I have tried with `maxrate` and `bufsize` but no real result.

* sources.txt example
file 'graphic.mp4'
file 'graphic.mp4'
file 'graphic.mp4'
file 'graphic.mp4'
file 'graphic.mp4'
file 'graphic.mp4'
and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ffmpeg process input as fast as possible. To slow it down to real time, add the '-re' flag when streaming to rtmp